# Changing body tag style through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to write a script to change the width of the page, considering user's client width.
It's something like this:

```
function adjustWidth() { 
    width = 0;
    if (window.innerHeight) {
        width = window.innerWidth;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else if (document.body) {
        width = document.body.clientWidth;
    }
    if (width < 1152) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.width="950px";
    }
    if (width >= 1152) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.width="1075px";
    }
}
window.onresize = function() {
    adjustWidth();
};
window.onload = function() {
    adjustWidth();
};
```

With this script I get an error from Firebug:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body").style is undefined
```

Now my question is, how can i access the style of body? Because in the css sheet its selector and width property are defined.

Comment: try **`getComputedStyle(elements).[style]`** and example **`window.getComputedStyle(document.body).width`** ... learn http://javascript.info/tutorial/styles-and-classes-getcomputedstyle

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That function returns a list of nodes, even though there's only one `<body>`.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style = ...
```

Now, that said, you may want to look into doing this with CSS instead of JavaScript. With CSS media queries, you make such adjustments:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1151px) {
  body { width: 950px; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1152px) {
  body { width: 1075px; }
}
```

Media queries work in IE9 and pretty much all other modern browsers.  For IE8 you can fall back to JavaScript or just let the body be 100% of the viewport width or something.

Comment: thanks alot. with media queries, should i be concerned about crossbrowser issues ?

Comment: @NOjAN well IE8 and earlier don't support media queries. Otherwise they're pretty well supported, even on iOS and Android etc.

Comment: Not need **getElementsByTagName** is exist bug other browser, try **`document.body`**

Comment: Always use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`

Answer (score 13):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style
```

Comment: Always use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`

Answer (score 11):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style = 'your code';
```

Example:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style = 'margin-top: -70px';
```

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array of nodes so you must use `[]` to access elements.

Try `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style`

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you get back from `document.getElementsByTagName("body")` is `HTMLCollection`. You should be able to use `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments (but strangely still missing among the answers), it should actually be [`document.body.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body). For example, `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#3f3f3f";`